# Except for Iron Router doesn't work

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would expect, that on the main page there is no output in the console. Instead I get the message 'do something'. But there is a except for 'home'.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
});
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    console.log('do something');
}, { except: ['home'] });

Router.route('/', function () {
    name: 'home',
    this.render('content', { to: 'content' }),
    this.render('navigation', { to: 'navigation' })
});
```

Comment: what the hell is `name: 'home'` in the '/' route? You seem to be mixing options with actions... That can't work, can it?

Comment: ya you're right, didn't even notice the lack of `action:` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing options with code in your '/' route. That can't work. Try one or the other, e.g., using all options:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    action: function() {
        this.render('content', { to: 'content' });
        this.render('navigation', { to: 'navigation' });
    }
});
```